# Generating new Rails app using "rails new myapp" fails on get_hosts_path in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

Under Windows, attempting to generate a new Rails app using `rails new myapp` will fail on `get_hosts_path`.  Actually, running Rails can fail on `get_hosts_path` in general depending on other options, like bootsnap.

An example of the error would be:

> ```
>    rails  importmap:install bin/rails aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `get_hosts_path' for module Win32::Resolv
> ```
>
> (NoMethodError)
> DefaultFileName = Win32::Resolv.get_hosts_path || IO::NULL
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ internal:C:/tools/ruby33/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in
> `require'

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, under Windows, Rails uses the `get_hosts_path` method that is only available in `win32/resolv`.  So, `win32/resolv` must be included in `config/boot.rb` to load Rails.

To generate a Rails app, create a file that can be called `win_resolv.rb`.  I put this in my projects folder so that is in the correct path for the `rails new` command.  In the file, enter this statement:

```
  prepend_to_file 'config/boot.rb', "require 'win32/resolv'\n"
```

Then, include it when generating the app, such as:

```
rails new myapp -m win_resolv.rb
```

You may need to include the path if win_resolv.rb is not in your current directory.